# Not able to publish app due to firebase SHA-1 issues

Tags: android, firebase

You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle that is signed with a key that is also used to sign APKs that are delivered to users. Because you are enrolled in App Signing by Google Play, you should sign your APK or Android App Bundle with a new key before you upload it. This is the error in playstore while publishing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the SHA-1 from the App Signing itself. It can be found in the inside Google Play Console under Release Management > App Signing.

Copy SHA-1 app signing certificate.

Paste the SHA-1 (also the SHA-256, just in case needed) fingerprints in the Firebase > Project Setting for the app.